# PUT request is not triggered (POST and GET work)

Tags: angular, httpclient

POST and GET method work perfectly but PUT method does not work.

I have a component with this function to update an Album data via Subscription:

```
onChangeTitle() {
    this.album.name = this.titleInput;
    const albumToEdit: IAlbumEdit = {
      'name': this.album.name,
      'description': this.album.description,
      'public': this.album.public
    };

    this.albumService.putAlbum(this.album.id, albumToEdit).subscribe(
      album => {
        this.album = album;
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError('no se ha podido modificar el álbum: ' + error);
        this.titleInput = this.album.name;
      }
    );
  }
```

The service has this function that return an Observable:

```
putAlbum(id, album: IAlbumEdit): Observable<IAlbum> {
    return this.http.put<IAlbum>(`${AppSettings.API_URL}/album/${id}`, album);
}
```

It is really easy but I don't understand why this httpclient put method is not triggered (I can see in network monitor in Firefox that any put is triggering).

Moreover I have an interceptor to add authorization header but it is not execute with PUT method.

My interceptor is this:

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add authorization header with jwt token if available
    console.log('intercept');
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
        }
      });
    }

    console.log(request);

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `onChangeTitle` method is called ? From where this method is called ?

Comment: Yes because logs. This method is called when a input is changed. I am sure method service is called but intercept is not called and PUT is never triggered.

Comment: Have you try to disable the interceptor to ensure that is not the source of your problem ?

Comment: I have just tried. With interceptor disabled works... at least the PUT is triggered.

Comment: please, check network tab in browser. I think CORS is not handled properly on the server side in this case. One unrelated tip that could be helpful: you can do something like `return next.handle(request).pipe(tap(item => console.log('next', item), err => console.log('error', err)))` to log result inside interceptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed. The problem was I imported HTTP_INTERCEPTOR in more than one module. I fixed the issue importing it only in app.module.ts.